# When is it preferable to cause a segfault in a watchdog thread versus exiting normally to stop a process?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, watchdog

I am wondering if there is **ever** a good reason to exit a watchdog thread in the manner depicted, versus exiting with `exit()`. In the code I came across that brought this question to mind, a segfault was caused by de-referencing a null pointer with the strange line `*(char **)0 = "watchdog timeout";`.

Unless I'm mistaken, a thread calling `exit()` terminates the entire process. I interpret a segfault as an error, and not intended behavior, but perhaps there are times when it is desired.

```c
void *watchdog_loop(void *arg) {
    time_t now;
    while(foo) {
        sleep(1);
        now = current_time();
        if (watchdog_timeout && now - bar > watchdog_timeout) {
            raise(SIGSEGV); //something went wrong
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: A seg fault cannot be guaranteed.  Use `exit()`.

Comment: If you want to raise a segmentation fault then I assume at least `raise(SIGSEGV)` is probably a better idea.

Comment: If you have an actual hardware watchdog, you usually reset it by writing an incorrect value to it. On a PC, none of what you are doing makes the slightest sense.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense either. It's not my work that I am questioning.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify for my original intent and in response to these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ever a time that it would be more desirable to have a watchdog loop segfault intentionally, versus exiting nonzero?

It is never desirable to elicit undefined behavior, which is what the example code does.  In particular, note well that that code is not required to cause a segfault to be delivered to the process, though it might reliably do so on certain systems.

However, one might indeed prefer to kill a process via a signal instead of by calling `exit()`, so as to achieve termination without executing any application or library cleanup code.  This is a plausible goal for a watchdog.  Even in that event, however,

1. Either the `raise()` or the `abort()` function would *definedly* cause a signal to be delivered to the process.
2. `SIGSEGV` seems an odd choice of signal.  Any of `SIGABRT`, `SIGTERM`, or `SIGKILL` would make more sense to me. Of those,

   - `SIGKILL` is not specified by the C language spec, but rather by POSIX (and maybe others).  On a POSIX system, `SIGKILL` cannot be blocked or caught, so it is a very good candidate for a signal to terminate the process as quickly and surely as possible.
   - `SIGABRT` is used by the `abort()` function, which also goes to some pains to try to overcome program resistance to being terminated that way.  This is the most natural standard function to use to trigger an intentional abnormal program termination.
   - `SIGTERM` can be caught and / or blocked, but unlike `SIGKILL`, it is defined by the C language specification, and therefore is more portable.  But I don't really see any advantage over `SIGABRT`, unless you *intend* to allow it to be handled.
3. Another alternative would be `_exit()` (POSIX) or `_Exit()` (C99 or later).  These perform a cleaner shutdown than you can expect from termination via a signal, but without executing most cleanup code.  Open files will be closed, and the parent process will observe the process to terminate normally with a failure status instead of terminating by being killed by a signal.

Comment: "note well that that code is not required to cause a segfault to be delivered to the process" Can you expand on this? Are you saying that a segfault within the thread might not affect the main process? I agree with you that it is not desirable to elicit undefined behavior, which is why this topic interested me. Sometimes there appears be a fine line between wizardry and ignorance, especially for someone with little experience like myself.

Comment: @qq4, I am saying that dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior.  *In general*, the manifestation of that UB does not necessarily involve a `SIGSEGV` being delivered to the process.  A different signal might be delivered instead (`SIGBUS`, for example), or the program might crash without receiving a signal, or the data  might be written to some address (maybe even address 0), or maybe nothing would happen.  This is likely to be fairly consistent within classes of machines and C implementations, but it is not universally consistent.